# Easyblog remove "recent blog posts" banner

Tags: joomla-3.x

I want to remove the "recent blog posts" banner from the main page of an easyblog.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can override the component view and change it. Here you can find the full explanation about overrides:

**Understanding Output Overrides**
http://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides